# Comic ballon like control in Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Im looking to create a control that would look like comic baloon.

In WPF i can use rectangle, lines and stuff like that, but in CF this controls dont exist.

any idea how could i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UserControl and override OnPaint.  Yes, it sounds painful - largely becasue it is.

Comment: maybe someone knows a sample where i can start? that would help alot !